# Notepad++ keep "Remember current session" AND have it ask to save unsaved files?

Tags: notepad++

I don't mind Notepad++'s "Remember current session for next launch" feature, but what I hate about it is that it automatically disables the program asking me to save unsaved files when I exit. Often I'm working on files which are shared via Dropbox or Google Drive, and I want to be sure the changes I've made will be reflected in the cloud version. If I neglect to save, obviously, they won't be. But at the same time, I do like the re-opening of the current session, especially the ability to have files that I'm working with temporarily, and don't really need to save as real files.

I've looked all through the settings, and can't find anything about prompting to save. Is there a plugin (or a setting I've missed) that will re-enable that prompt without having to disable the saved-session behavior?

Comment: You may have more chance at [Npp community](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/community/)